# Swift: Background disappears after addSubview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit, uikit

I have a GameOver class which show a backgroundcolor and a playAgain button.
After adding "view.addSubview(self.playAgainButton)" the backgroundcolor pops up and suddenly it disappears from screen. The playAgain-Button is still there.

If I remove the addSubview Call the backgroundcolor stays there.

Can anybody help me?

```
class GameOver: SKScene{
  var playAgainButton = UIButton()
  var playAgainButtonImage = UIImage(named: "PlayAgainButton")

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

     self.playAgainButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
     self.playAgainButton = setImage(playAgainButtonImage, forState: .Normal)
     self.playAgainButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2, 190, 70)
     self.playAgainButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)
     self.playAgainButton.layer.zPosition = 0

     // If I add this line -> backgroundcolor disappears
     view.addSubview(self.playAgainButton)

  }
}
```

My GameScene gameOver function lookes like this (maybe is there the error?)

```
func gameOver() {
   let skView = self.view! as SKView
   skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

   self.scene?.removeFromParent()

   let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.grayColor(), duration: 1.0)
   transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false

   var scene: GameOver!
   scene = GameOver(size: skView.bounds.size)

   scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

   skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to set the background color on the view you are moving to or the view that you are currently at (moving away from)?

Comment: Looks like he is setting the background on the Scene, but then is throwing a button on top of the view,  are you sure that the scene itself is not disappearing, not just the background color?

Comment: @Putz1103: The background color of the view I´m moving to disappears

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Isn´t the view a part of the scene? How can the button be visible but the backgroundcolor not. Can you give me some advise how to fix that?

Comment: I found the issue myself. I have to add the subview to the superview.
**view.superview?.addSubview(self.playAgainButton)**

Comment: no the scene is a part of the view not the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the subview to the superview

Change

```
view.addSubview(self.playAgainButton)
```

to

```
view.superview?.addSubview(self.playAgainButton)
```

that solves the problem